# Name clash between class static member and another type

Tags: c#, .net

I just declared

```
public static class DefaultComparers
{
    public readonly IComparer TextComparer = new TextComparer(new CompositeIndexedComparer<string>());

    private static IDictionary<string, IComparer> DefaultComparers()
    {
       return new Dictionary<string, IComparer>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) {
                {"txt", TextComparer}
       };
    }
}
```

however in the same namespace is already a class called `TextComparer` and hence the `DefaultComparers` method doesn't compile. If it was a non-static method I could easily fix it by using `this.TextComparer`. What is the alternative in static context?

Comment: You can prefix it with the namespace.

Comment: The answer from Reza gives a reason why `DefaultComparers` method can't have the same name as its containing class. However, having a field `TextComparer` with the same name as an "exterior" type should not lead to compile-time errors. Not that it is wise ... However, are you trying to access a non-static field from a `static` method? Well no, you can't have a non-static member in a `static class`, so that is one additional problem with your code. Please try to give a more exact picture of what code you have!

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum The question is very confused, but there is no need to qualify if one is a type and the other is a field/variable. The compiler will know from context if a type or a value is expected. However, when you need to qualify a `static` member, instead of `this.MemberName`, you use `ClassName.MemberName`. Namespace is not needed except if there is something the asker didn't tell us.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen you are of course correct, I assumed OP was using the terminology incorrectly and needed to qualify a class name from a namespace.

Answer (score 6):

The name of this method is as same as your class, which can't be, compiler suppose it as constructor for your class so it shouldn't have return type

```
private static IDictionary<string, IComparer> DefaultComparers()
{
   return new Dictionary<string, IComparer>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) {
            {"txt", TextComparer}
   };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems based on wrong premises. Your code has several other problems, but the problem you ask for, is non-existent. This compiles flawlessly:

```
class ConflictName
{
}
class GoodName
{
    static object ConflictName = new ConflictName();

    static Dictionary<string, object> ANOTHERGoodName()
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "txt", ConflictName }
        };
    }
}
```

The compiler knows the difference between a ***type*** (the `class ConflictName`) and a ***value*** (the field `ConflictName` inside the second class).

However, in *other* cases where it is necessary to qualify a `static` member (for example because it is hidden by a local variable defined inside the same method), you just prefix the class name, e.g. `GoodName.ConflictName` instead of just `ConflictName`.